# Instrumenting pulsar functions

Tags: open-telemetry, apache-pulsar

Has anyone had success instrumenting pulsar functions with otel? I am currently attempting the following, but not having much success.

1. Starting a pulsar-standalone docker container with `conf/functions_worker.yml` updated to include:

   ```
   additionalJavaRuntimeArguments: ['-javaagent:/target/otel/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar']
   ```
2. Create a pulsar function via

   ```
   ./bin/pulsar-admin --admin-url http://localhost:8081 functions create
   ```

   i.e. not using **localrun** (which does not work with additionalJavaRuntimeArguments)

Ref: https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/next/functions-runtime-java-options/

When testing the above, i see no evidence that my agent config has been applied, and it does not print the JVM args [1] - but either way, my approach is not having an affect it seems..). To be clear, the function is called, and I can see the `conf/functions_worker.yml` file's update, but just no instrumentation is occurring.

Currently not sure if this is a valid approach, so any direction will be much appreciated. For example, I am not sure if i should use `customRuntimeOptions` option instead when creating the function (as described here https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/next/functions-cli/)

Otel ref: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/

[1] This pulsar function code does not print my custom args

```
        val runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean()
        val arguments = runtimeMxBean.inputArguments
        context.logger.info("arguments $arguments")
```

Comment: additionalJavaRuntimeArguments is the correct approach and does work
also need to be on version 2.10.0+ for additionalJavaRuntimeArguments to work
the trace propagation seems broken, where the traceId is received by the function, but not sent by the function.. I plan to create a github tickry for pulsar java otel team